# assigning to arg inside function definition?

Tags: basic, gw-basic

Trying to read some old BASIC code to do a port, and coming across this mind-bending concept:

```
1150 DEF FNB(Q)=Q+8*((Q=9)-(Q=0))
```

What... is going on here?  How can you assign to the parameter like that?  Why isn't this equivalent to `Q+8*(9-0)`?

I wrote a little demo to investigate, but it didn't yield anything that I expected:

```
10 DEF FNB(Q)=Q+8*((Q=9)-(Q=0))
20 PRINT FNB(1)
30 PRINT FNB(2)
20 PRINT FNB(3)
30 PRINT FNB(10)
RUN
 1
 2
 3
 10
Ok
```

I must be doing something wrong, because `FNB` can't be an identity function.

Can someone explain what BASIC is actually doing in this function?  And why my demo isn't being helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, I just got it.

That's not *assignment* inside the function, it's an equality test!

If they are equal, it returns -1 *(why...)*, else 0.

For example:

```
10 print 9=9
20 print 9=8
RUN
-1
 0
Ok
```

Man, it's been a *long* time since I used a language that used `=` for equality...

Comment: `-1 = NOT 0` (that is a bitwise `NOT`, e.g. `0b111 = NOT 0b000`). As for why it was done that way, I have no idea except for perhaps some ancient efficiency reason that is lost to the ages now. I'm not sure if Visual Basic (the newer .NET-compatible versions) also makes the results of comparisons equal to one of 0 or -1. BTW, the `=` character being used for both assignment and equality testing was a trait of most BASIC dialects, and I can only assume that it still is.

Comment: Ah, a bitflip of 0!  That makes sense, in an old-school mindset.  GW-BASIC is the only dialect I ever dabbled in, and not since I was like 13, back in the early 90s.  I didn't *learn* the answer to this, rather I suddenly remembered it.  :)

Comment: I was fortunate enough to be able to use QBASIC as one of my first BASIC languages, which was a remarkable improvement over GW-BASIC with proper subprocedures and functions à la Pascal (though `DEF FNxxx` and `GOSUB`/`RETURN` were still available). Anyway, I'm glad you remembered the syntax that now seems strange to many people these days. :)